# How to make AngularJS ignore ajax OPTIONS method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, angularjs

When making a cross-domain Ajax POST request, AngularJS sends an HTTP OPTIONS request first. jQuery does the same, and I understand this is part of the spec. The difference is if there's an error with the OPTIONS request (e.g. server doesn't support it, as is often the case) jQuery will continue and make the POST request anyway where AngularJS just silently fails and gives up. Is there a way to force it to make the POST request regardless ?

Comment: I think OPTIONS requests are handled at browser level. Looking at the source of $http in angular and XHR in jQuery, I don't see any references to OPTIONS requests but there's some specific code involving headers for cross domain requests in jQuery that's perhaps what makes the difference. Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js and  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js . My solution to that problem is to make a reverse proxy to inject the correct Allow-XXXX headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  Guillaume86 said the OPTIONS request (aka preflight CORS request ) is sent by the browser if the request is made cross domain. See here the specs http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ . The browser will cache it if you set a cache header. E.g :

```
 Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```